# non-native mobile app approach that can send GPS data to a server while app is in background

Tags: android, ios, gps, cross-platform, background-process

We are creating an MVP (minimum viable product) for a business service.

We want to create an app that could be run on multiple mobile platform in one go. Technologies such as Construct 2 allow us to create a prototype of the app very quickly. However, we come across the problem that HTML5 app that got turned into mobile apps (using Crosswalk, for example) stop working when the mobile screen is off. We need the app to send GPS data back to a server while the app is in the background.

We have looked around in Stackoverflow, and lots of questions and answers seem to point out for native approach. However, this is an MVP and we want to reduce cost as much as possible as going for native approaches mean making 2 apps for iOS and Android. We also want to setup the MVP as quickly as possible to study the business service's feasibility.

Furthermore, another reason that we want to go with non-native route is maintenance cost. If we have to go native route, it means we are responsible for maintaining multiple mobile apps. It is preferable that we have only one app to take care off.

Our requirement is:

- Quickly prototyping a single app that could run on multiple mobile platform
- Can request GPS data while in background. (ex. screen is off or user viewing other apps)
- Can send data back to server in background. (We are using AJAX right now at the moment.)

We mentioned Construct 2 above. This is one of the technologies we quickly used for prototyping. Another one we came across is Codiqa. There are a few other more tools that allow you to drag and drop and create apps with ease like this.

Some of the online tools such as Codiqa advertise that they could turn the app into native. However, what we worried is, are these apps actually just HTML5 wrapped into Crosswalk or the like or not. We have tried exporting HTML5 from Construct 2 and go for a Crosswalk approach via Intel XDK. The result is our app stop running if we turn off the screen.

Because of this, we believe HTML5 approach might not work, unless we are missing something. Is there any **other** non-native mobile app approach that can send GPS data to a server and also allowing the app to run in the background in this case?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html

Comment: @eee sorry, but could you clarify how is your link related? I mentioned non-native approach.

Comment: @karl - You need to wrap your app in a hybrid wrapper to be able to run background services and get access to data when the phone screen is off, or the app is in the background.  https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/cordova-plugin-background-app  let's you run background services in a Cordova app.